# how to set ListView background item color in android

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview

I have a Custom Listview with three TextView. Every row will show person name, email and day.Now I want to set a red color for which person's days are less than 120 and I also want to set a green color for which person's days are greater than 120.How to solve my problem??Any help will be appreciated.

[My ListView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhGMu.png)

person_show

```
   public class person_show extends Activity
{
    static int total_day;
    List<personInfo>PersonInfo;
    public MyAdapter adapter;
    static Vector<String>email = new Vector<>();
    static Vector<String>name = new Vector<>();
    static Vector<String>city = new Vector<>();
    static String[] Name,Email,City;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personlistview);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        //show_person();
        Person_Show();
    }

    private void Person_Show()
    {
        PersonInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            String[] value = new String[]{" No Data Found"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.persontextview,value);
            list.setAdapter(Adapter);

            PersonInfo.add(new personInfo("abc","abc@gmail.com","65 days"));
            PersonInfo.add(new personInfo("xyz","xyz@gmail.com","130 days"));
            PersonInfo.add(new personInfo("pqr","pqr@gmail.com","70 days"));
            PersonInfo.add(new personInfo("ABC","ABC@gmail.com","140 days"));
            for(int i = 0;i<email.size();i++)
                PersonInfo.add(new personInfo(name.get(i),email.get(i),"150 days"));
            adapter = new MyAdapter(this,PersonInfo);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    List<personInfo>PersonInfo;
    Context context;
    public MyAdapter(Context context,List<personInfo>personInfo)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.PersonInfo = personInfo;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PersonInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return PersonInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_layout,parent,false);
        TextView txt_name,txt_email,txt_phone;
        txt_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t_name);
        txt_email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t_email);
        txt_phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.t_phone);
        txt_name.setText(PersonInfo.get(position).getName());
        txt_email.setText(PersonInfo.get(position).getEmail());
        txt_phone.setText(PersonInfo.get(position).getPhone());
        return view;
    }
}
```

personInfo

```
public class personInfo
{
    String name,phone,email;
    public personInfo(String name,String email,String phone)
    {
        this.name = name ;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: So what u have tried? What problem are you facing ?

Comment: plesae paste some adapter code.

Comment: check days and set color to red/green depending on value to rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));

Comment: Did you check my answer ??

Comment: yeah,It's work.Thank you for your answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your **Adapter** code . At first Check **`days`** . **`days`** holds no of days . **`days`** should be **`int`** type .

Check below **`LOGIC`** .

```
String[] splited = PersonInfo.get(position).getPhone().split("\\s+"); //65 days
String str_Days=splited[0]; //65
int days = Integer.valueOf(str_Days);

if (days<=120) 
{
        Your_LayoutOBJ.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));
}
 else 
 {
        Your_LayoutOBJ.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
 }
```

**FYI**

**`Your_LayoutOBJ`** is your RootLayout .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    >

    .....

</RelativeLayout>
```

Declare **`LIKE Textview and Set background color`** .

Answer (score 0):

Add This code in Adapter or View Holder if you use RecyclerView

```
 if(yourObject.days>120){
    rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContex‌​t, R.color.green));
    }else{
    rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContex‌​t, R.color.red));
    }
```